# Python-Django User-posts

Tags: python, django

I have a question I'm writing a Django project and I'm learning well 
but I don't known how to make.

How can I controller id to user  who user which send to post? Sorry my English is not good, I'll exemplify so that you understand me:

user = a
user = b

---- user "a" is login -----

(hello this is a first post ) user by a

-----user "a" is logout------

-----user "b" is login ------

(hello this is a second post ) user by b

-----user "b" is logout -----

I want that my project behaves like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a logged user calls a django view then the `request.user` attribute contains the `User` instance of the logged user.

So add the `ForeignKey(User)` field to your `Post` model and assign this field in the view:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And then in your view:

```
@login_required
def post(request):
    message = request.POST['message']
    Post.objects.create(user=request.user, message=message)
    return HttpResponse('Message posted')
```

Of course your view shouldn't be like this.  It is just the minimal working example.  In real life you have to use django model forms and templates.